# How can I create an alternate full-HTML editor for posts?

Tags: html-editor

I have created a custom post type; the content of this custom post type should be a full html page - not just a snippet of html.

The standard editor appears to interfere with the html and it does not appear to be ready to handle a full html page source as its content.

Ideally, I would love to be able to disable the 'editor' capability for this custom post type and replace the editor with a custom plugin - only, I'm not sure about the best course of action to implement this functionality. I am open to writing the plugin myself, but it would be nice to learn that such a plugin exists already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Problem

It seems that you're using the normal theme template files for posts and pages to display your custom post type. This means, that you also got the `wp_head()` hook and other template, that output default (post/page specific) things.

### The solution

Add a template file to your theme, that's named `single-{$post_type}.php` and nothing than the loop with only `echo get_the_content()` in it. This way you can build your HTML without any interference.

`get_the_content()` has no filters applied, that normally get attached to `the_content()`.

Comment: kaiser, I have done that and it works quite well - however, this "single-{$post_type}.php" page outputs the_content() unaltered, so I would need the_content() to be a full html page, including <html>..</html> - how can I edit such a full html page in the custom post edit admin page? Basically, I need to serve the_content() as-is, and be able to store full html pages (that I do not know the content of beforehand) into the custom post type content field.

Comment: First: See edit. Second: Simply add your complete html (including the `<html>` tags) in your editors HTML view.